# Multiple file upload with rest-assured

Tags: java, postman, rest-assured

I have a post api call which allows me to upload multiple images within form-data parameter named "file"
In postman, i can send multiple file in form-data having key "file" and values as multiple file

I want to simulate the same call with rest-assured java client. I could upload single file with rest-assured but unable to upload multiple files.

Following is the rest-assured code for single file upload:

> ```
> File sheetFile = new File(sheetPath.get(0));
> response = RestAssured.
>           given().
>               headers(headers).
>               formParameter("studentDetail",
>                       "{"+
>                       "\"userId\" : "+PropFileHandler.readProperty("psUserId")+
>                       ",\"institutionId\" : "+PropFileHandler.readProperty("institution_id")+
>                       ",\"externalUserId\" : "+PropFileHandler.readProperty("user_id")+
>                       ",\"tokenId\" : \"12000\""+
>                       ",\"imagePathStatus\" : \"\""+
>                       "}").
>               formParameter("clientType", getData("ps_bulk_upload_image.clientType")).
>               multiPart("file", sheetFile). #here i want to upload multile files
>           when().
>               post(relativePath).
>           then().
>               statusCode(200).
>               body(matchesJsonSchema(new File(test.cngActions.getJsonSchemaDirectoryPath()+
>                       getData("ps_bulk_upload_image.schemaPath")))).
>               extract().response();
> ```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You only has to call multipart method **with the same controlName** all the times that you need.

```
RestAssuredMockMvc
    .given()
        .log().all()
        .headers(httpHeaders)
        .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA.toString())
        .multiPart("content", file1)
        .multiPart("content", file2)
```

With that you send the following request

```
Multiparts:     ------------
            Content-Disposition: form-data; name = content; filename = test1.txt
            Content-Type: application/octet-stream

            C:\Users\mgagomez\AppData\Local\Temp\junit7193983138466861544\test1.txt
            ------------
            Content-Disposition: form-data; name = content; filename = test2.txt
            Content-Type: application/octet-stream

            C:\Users\mgagomez\AppData\Local\Temp\junit7193983138466861544\test2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call `multiPart` multiple times.

See here: https://blog.jayway.com/2011/09/15/multipart-form-data-file-uploading-made-simple-with-rest-assured/

Relevant code:

```
given().
  multiPart("file1", new File("/home/johan/some_large_file.bin")).
  multiPart("file2", new File("/home/johan/some_other_large_file.bin")).
  multiPart("file3", "file_name.bin", inputStream).
  formParam("name", "value").
expect().
  body("fileUploadResult", is("OK")).
when().
  post("/advancedFileUpload");
```